# Something curious about Xubuntu's ping

Tags: ubuntu, ping

I'm curious about something. When I pinged the local IP, I got these results

```
PING 192.168.8.100 (192.168.8.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.8.100: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms

--- 192.168.8.100 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7155ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.049/0.058/0.061/0.003 ms
```

Individually the latency is as expected, but why is it that in the statistics, the time is listed as 7155ms?

Answer (score 0):

`ping` waits 1 second between each ping, and you have 8 pings. To be clear, that's wall time, not the sum of the time for all round trips.